# Deploy a Yeoman Application With Gulp

Tags: gulp, yeoman

Generator: https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular

On my recent projects I just pushed everything with git even the minified versions. But the dist/ folder is on the gitignore.

I read you shouldn't store minified etc. versions anyways in your git, because you don't need version tracking there.

This gulp plugin uses git: http://yeoman.io/learning/deployment.html

**1) So do I push it via git and then build it again on my server with gulp build?**

**2) What is a good way to automate it? I would like to do s.th. like this:**

`gulp serve:dist` Serve it on my localhost 
`gulp serve:server` Push it to my server delete old version and build the new version there

Answer (score 1):

No. What you should do is work locally with all your project and when you have to deploy the minified file, only run `gulp build`. The `dist` directory will be created and the only thing you have to do is to initialize git in here with `git init` and then add your server as remote.

You only have to re-run the build and push the content of your `dist` when you want to update it.

I don't think a simple thing as this is worth to optimize.

Comment: 'the only thing you have to do is to initialize git in here with `git init` and then add your server as remote.'  _Lost me_. But pointed me in the right direction. This [github docs page](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/) helped out a lot.  Question - @Apercu - are you saying you only use build tools like gulp and grunt for local development - and just deploy the dist file?

Comment: Yep, I deploy only the content of the `dist` directory. Sorry if I explain badly, the `git init` command is here to separate the generated directory from your real project, so you make sure it will not be pushed with your sources if you use a source control system (since it has a `.git`).